# how to find special characters present in a String in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

When a string has special characters then how to find out in FileMaker scripting.

For example we have ABC$XYZ then in scripting we need to find only charaters like A to Z or a to z or 0 to 1 exist or any other characters also exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filter function combined with the Length function should work for finding out if other characters exist, for example:

```
Let ( [
    originalString = "ABC$XYZ";
    originalStringLength = Length ( originalString );

    // all characters would need to be listed below
    filterSet = "abcd...zABCD...Z012...9";

    filteredString = Filter ( originalString ; filterSet );
    filteredStringLength = Length ( filteredString )
] ;
    If ( filteredStringLength = originalStringLength ;
        "No special characters." ;
        "Special characters." )
)
```

To find out what those characters are, however, you may need to use the Substitute function.

Additional reading:

- Filter Function: http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.52.html
- Substitute Function: http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.88.html#1031764